# volume undelete on a HP MSA

Tags: storage, restore, undelete

Is it possible to undelete a volume in a HP MSA 2000?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, once you blow away a storage volume (a LUN) it's gone.

Comment: I'm going to accept your answer, just because you had the guts to say it. And because it's true!

Answer (score 3):

Not entirely true.  It is possible but there is no guarantee that it will work.
The basic steps are:
Recreate the LUN and make sure it is EXACTLY the same size as the delete LUN.
Present the LUN to a server and use FDISK or equivalent to recreate the partition.

In my case I was using the LUN on a VMWARE ESXi host and once I had recreated the LUN, I presented this to the ESXi host and used the following article to re-create the partition (setting the start and end blocks of the partition to be EXACTLY the same as it was before the LUN was deleted). See http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2046610

I had to do quite a bit of trial and error on this and the whole process took 3 hours which was a lot quicker than having to try to restore 2TB of data.